# Ao chamar Modal, tela é exibida e some e a execução continua

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, modal

A idéia de Modal é uma tela que é exibida e a tela que está por baixo fica desabilitada e a execução do programa só segue após fechar o Modal. Comigo está assim. O Modal é exibido e o programa fecha ele sozinho e a execução do programa segue. 
Esse é o modal

```
<!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

E fiz isso no botão

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-verde wd-270 f-right" value="Salvar" onclick="startLoading();" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" />
```

Como evitar a execução automática, seguir somente quando eu fechar o Modal?

Comment: Suas tags estão erradas, pq não bootstrap, Js...?

Comment: O que essa função startLoading(); faz?

Comment: Ela já estava no sistema, apenas um loading. Esse sistema já existia, eu apenas estou dando manutenção e preciso colocar um Modal

Comment: SE o assunto é modal, ou seja CSS e vc está utilizando as classes do bootstrap, se você usar as tags corretas será mais fácil de encontrar pessoas para te ajudarem